# Finding Duplicates in the Value of HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, contains

```
private HashMap <Integer, String> ID_TAGS;
    private HashMap <String, Integer> TAGS_ID;
    private HashMap <String, String> TAGS_TRANSLATIONS;
    private final ArrayList <Integer> INCLUSIONLIST;
    private final ArrayList <Integer> EXCLUSIONLIST;



public DuplicationFinder(HashMap <Integer, String> id_tags, HashMap <String, String> tags_translations, ArrayList <Integer> exclusionList, ArrayList <Integer> inclusionList) {
    this.ID_TAGS = id_tags;
    this.TAGS_TRANSLATIONS = tags_translations;
    this.INCLUSIONLIST = inclusionList;
    this.EXCLUSIONLIST = exclusionList;
    TAGS_ID = new HashMap <>();
    for(Entry <Integer, String> e : ID_TAGS.entrySet()){
        TAGS_ID.put(e.getValue(), e.getKey());
    }
}
/**
 * Findet die Duplikate und gibt die ID's zurück.
 * @return
 */
public Set <Integer> findDuplicates(){
    Set <Integer> duplicates = new LinkedHashSet <>();
    for(Entry <Integer, String> e : ID_TAGS.entrySet()) {
        HashMap <String, String> cloneWithoutTag= new HashMap <>(TAGS_TRANSLATIONS);
        int id = e.getKey();
        String tag = e.getValue();
        cloneWithoutTag.remove(tag);
        if(cloneWithoutTag.containsValue(TAGS_TRANSLATIONS.get(tag))) {
            duplicates.add(id);
        }
    }
    duplicates.addAll(EXCLUSIONLIST);
    duplicates.removeAll(INCLUSIONLIST);
    Iterator<Integer> nextD = duplicates.iterator();
    while(nextD.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(lookUp(ID_TAGS.get(nextD.next())));
    }
    return duplicates;
}

public String lookUp(String tag) {
    return TAGS_TRANSLATIONS.get(tag);
}

public int getID(String tag) {
    return TAGS_ID.get(tag);
}
```

}

I don't know if anybody can help me with that. I'll try to find some Keys with the same Value in the TAGS_TRANSLATIONS-HashMap. My thought was that when the chosen key is not int the clone of the map you can look if the same value is still in there. It's working so far but i have a Problem, some Values like "Meeting" are only one time in there and also got in the Output.  Now i'll try to find the Error. Thanks in advance for help :)

Comment: What does your code actually do?  You've dumped this on us and then asked us to fix it.

Comment: Yeah thats what i tried to explain, i have HashMap with <ID, Tags> and these Tags refers to an Tag, which i implemented in an another HasMap <Tags, Translation>. Now ill try to find Duplicates in Translations and i want to add the ID to a Duplicate Set. But i have about 10 Duplicates in it ,that aren't no Duplicates

Comment: I attempted an answer below, since your above comment makes the question clear enough to know what you are trying to ask.  For future reference, please ask clearer questions.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you have the following map:

```
Map<Tags, Translation> someMap;
```

You could get all the values as a collection, which would include duplicates, and then use `Collections#frequency()` to find the frequency of each item.  If the frequency be greater than one, then the translation is a duplicate.

```
Collection<Translation> translations = someMap.values();
Set<Translation> dupeSet = new HashSet<>();

for (Translation t : translations) {
    if (Collections.frequency(translations, t) > 1) {
        dupeSet.add(t);
    }
}
```

Note that this code *will* touch each duplicate translation, but since we are storing the duplicates in a set, a given duplicate translation should appear only once in the final result.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, i made it a slight different way. I use now a Wrapper Class and that make this really easy. The Problem was that i compared the data from 2 Databases and some Tags had the same ID, so the Set was the Problem in here.